# How to search contacts with certain prefix say, "Dr"?

Tags: search, search-results, custom-search, search-builder, quicksearch

I want to search contacts with prefix "Dr." and if possible make it as a smart group. How to achieve these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is job for the Search Builder that you can find in the *Search* menu

1. Select *Individual*
2. Select *Individual Prefix*
3. Complete with = and the desired title.

When the results are shown you can create a Smart Group for this search.